# response.xpath not returning value

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract the pricing for an item on the following page: https://www.lowesforpros.com/pd/DEWALT-20-Volt-Max-1-2-in-Cordless-Brushless-Drill/1000135807

In the following code nothing is returned:

```
response.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div[6]/section[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[1]/text()").extract()]
```

I have looked at the source and do not see any indication of JS in use to pull the pricing.

Answer (score 0):

What about simple:

```
response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="price"]/@content').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 0):

The price section is not included in the basic HTML of the page. It is loaded by javascript after the completion of page loading. Consequently, the path is not specified anything. You have to use javascript renderer engines such as [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) or web drivers like [Selenium](https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/index.html)